# Is this an incorrect Mann-Whitney U statistic using Apache Commons?

Tags: python, java, statistics

Using the staology.com website, I did a Mann-Whitney test in both Java and in Python. Yet, the Java version appears to be incorrect or I did something wrong. The Python logic matches the website (https://www.statology.org/mann-whitney-u-test/).

Here is the Java code:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.inference.MannWhitneyUTest;

 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Creating two sample datasets
        double[] data1 = {3, 5, 1, 4, 3, 5};
        double[] data2 = {4, 8, 6, 2, 1, 9};

        // Compute and print ranks
        MannWhitneyUTest mannWhitneyUTest = new MannWhitneyUTest();
        double uStatistic = mannWhitneyUTest.mannWhitneyU(data1, data2);
        double pValue = mannWhitneyUTest.mannWhitneyUTest(data1, data2);

        // Printing U statistic
        System.out.println("U-statistic: " + uStatistic);

        // Printing P value
        System.out.println("P-value: " + pValue);
    }
```

The output from this code does not match the website:

```
U-statistic: 23.0
P-value: 0.4233396415824435
```

---

The Python logic, on the other hand, does match the website:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu

data1 = [3, 5, 1, 4, 3, 5]
data2 = [4, 8, 6, 2, 1, 9]

# Compute and print ranks
u_statistic, p_value = mannwhitneyu(data1, data2)

# Printing the ranks
print('U-statistic: ', u_statistic)

# Computing and printing p-value
print('P-value: ', p_value)

U-statistic:  13.0
P-value:  0.46804160590041655
```

Did I do something incorrect in the Java version?

If so, I don't see what it is.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the Apache Math library. I'm leaving the posting to include detail about what got returned in the java version. Supposedly, this problem is fixed in the 4.0 version, but it's only (as I find) in beta from Dec 2022. (This is February 2024).

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer, but when I looked up that apache commons math library, the version is 4, so it's probably an issue in that Java library.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to [this online tool](https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/mannwhitney/default2.aspx), and put the data, you'll see that the U value is 13. This is probably because the Java Apache Commons Math Library you're using is version 3, and the current version is 4.

For maven, just remove the dependency for math 3, and replace it with the following:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-math4-legacy</artifactId>
      <version>4.0-beta1</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the final java code:

```java
import org.apache.commons.math4.legacy.stat.inference.MannWhitneyUTest;

public class App{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creating two sample datasets
        double[] data1 = {3, 5, 1, 4, 3, 5};
        double[] data2 = {4, 8, 6, 2, 1, 9};

        // Compute and print ranks
        MannWhitneyUTest mannWhitneyUTest = new MannWhitneyUTest();
        double uStatistic = mannWhitneyUTest.mannWhitneyU(data1, data2);
        double pValue = mannWhitneyUTest.mannWhitneyUTest(data1, data2);

        // Printing U statistic
        System.out.println("U-statistic: " + uStatistic);

        // Printing P value
        System.out.println("P-value: " + pValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was only able to find the beta1 version of Java Apache Commons Math Library. That version did not appear to have this statistical test in it. Do you know of a maven dependency for a later version? Thanks again.

Comment: Hello @Morkus, I've updated the answer. beta1 version of Java Apache Commons Math Library works. It gave me the value 13. I'm not a Java developer, but I could figure out how to include that specific dependency in the maven project, you just have to edit the pom.xml file, or you could add it with the GUI if you're using eclipse or intellij (I use VScode lol).

I hope that helped

Comment: I hadn't imported some of the transitive dependencies. The "beta1" version now produces 13 for the U statistic, but it's ranks don't match the python version and it's p-value doesn't match the python program either. I may need to manually do this test. The website mentioned above gives "The p-value is .47152.", but the Java logic using the "beta" Apache math 4, gives  P-Value: 0.42333.  The Python program gives the p-value at about 0.47.

Comment: Maybe the first tool was kinda bugged. I used [this](https://astatsa.com/WilcoxonTest/) tool and [this](https://www.statskingdom.com/170median_mann_whitney.html) one, they both showed 0.468 p-value. I'm not sure if all of them are true and Java is false. I've asked chatgpt about it, it said that when calculating the p-value there's a difference in something related to `tie-breaking procedures`, which I have no clue of. I think your best choice is to go with the python script (and call it from java maybe) or to manually implement that mann whitney u test algorithm. \

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your input! :)